# How to define and plot a maximum function?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization

Define a function $g$ as follows:

```
f = 2/((x1 + Sqrt[3] x2)^2 + (y1 + Sqrt[3] y2)^2)
X = vx1^2*D[D[f, x1], x1] + vx2^2*D[D[f, x2], x2] + 2 vx1*vx2*D[D[f, x1], x2] 
Y= vx1*D[f, x1] + vx2*D[f, x2] 
g=X+Y^2
```

The function $g$ is clearly a function in 6 variables ($vx1,vx2,x1,x2,y1,y2$).

Now I want to define a function in two variables $max$ as the maximum of $g$ for $x1,x2,y1,y2$ which vary in the following hypersurface

```
H = ImplicitRegion[{3 (-x1^2 - y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2) + 
 2 Sqrt[3] (x1*x2 + y1*y2) == 0}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
```

So I want to (but I don't know how to) define the function 
$max:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$max(vx1,vx2)=\max\limits_{(x1,x2,y1,y2)\in H}g(vx1,vx2,x1,x2,y1,y2)$$

All I could think of is the command

```
FindMaximum[{g, {x1, y1, x2, y2} ∈ H}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
```

but this doesn't define a function, it just gives the maximum of $g$ for specific values of $vx1,vx2$.

How can I define the function $max$? It's important to me to **define it as a function** because I need to

- derive it in its smooth points
- plot it
- define other functions which involve $max$ in their definition

How can I do it?

EDIT: I followed the suggestions of user Corey979 and defined the function max[vx1,vx2], but with FindMaximum substitued by MaxValue, since I'm interested in the maximum value (as I thought was clear in my definition). But then I'm not able to do any operation with the function max:

Any of these operations

```
D[max[vx1, vx2], vx1]

Plot3D[max[vx1, vx2], {vx1, -10, 10}, {vx2, -10, 10}]

FindMaximum[{max[vx1, vx2]}, {vx1, vx2}]
```

Will require an extremely long computational time and will give no output.
Which is strange, since with my old code

```
f = 2/((x1 + Sqrt[3] x2)^2 + (y1 + Sqrt[3] y2)^2)
X = vx1^2*D[D[f, x1], x1] + vx2^2*D[D[f, x2], x2] + 2 vx1*vx2*D[D[f, x1], x2] 
Y= vx1*D[f, x1] + vx2*D[f, x2] 
g=X+Y^2
H = ImplicitRegion[{3 (-x1^2 - y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2) + 
 2 Sqrt[3] (x1*x2 + y1*y2) == 0}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
FindMaximum[{g, {x1, y1, x2, y2} ∈ H}, {vx1,vx2,x1, y1, x2, y2}]
```

I was able to get the answer

```
{2.39111, {vx1 -> 1.55608, vx2 -> 1.96316, x1 -> 0.810245, y1 -> -0.236216, x2 -> 1.34919, y2 -> -0.463331}}
```

**Is there a better way to define max in such a way that it will be possible to perform operations with it?**

Comment: What are some typical values of `vx1` and `vx2`?

Comment: Let's just assume that the domain of $h$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The underscore [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) (`_`) is used when defining functions, like `f[x_]:=x^2`; then you call it normally with `f[x]`. You can't have them in expressions like `D[max[vx1_, vx2_], vx1]` or `FindMaximum[{max[vx1_, vx2_]}, {vx1, vx2}]`. That's a simple syntax error.

Comment: Also, you should read the docs of `FindMaximum` as you misunderstand its output - with my def of `max`, `FindMaximum[{max[vx1, vx2]}, {vx1, vx2}]` makes no sense.

Comment: I corrected the $_$ error. As I wrote in the definition of $h$, $h$ is defined as the maximum value of g. should I substitute FindMaximum with MaxValue in your code? If yes, then I'm not able to do any computation with max function, because the computational time is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your functions as *functions*:

```
f[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 2/((x1 + Sqrt[3] x2)^2 + (y1 + Sqrt[3] y2)^2)

X[vx1_, vx2_, x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 vx1^2*D[D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x1], x1] + 
  vx2^2*D[D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x2], x2] + 
  2 vx1*vx2*D[D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x1], x2]

Y[vx1_, vx2_, x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 vx1*D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x1] + vx2*D[f[x1, x2, y1, y2], x2]

g[vx1_, vx2_, x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 X[vx1, vx2, x1, x2, y1, y2] + Y[vx1, vx2, x1, x2, y1, y2]^2

H = ImplicitRegion[{3 (-x1^2 - y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2) + 2 Sqrt[3] (x1*x2 + y1*y2) == 0}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
```

Define the max as a function:

```
max[vx1_, vx2_] := 
 FindMaximum[{g[vx1, vx2, x1, x2, y1, 
    y2], {x1, y1, x2, y2} ∈ H}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
```

Then

```
m = max[1000., 1000.]
```

[image]

(The value of the maximum is a numerical zero; you might want to incorporate `Chop` in `max`.) Verify that the solution is in `H`:

```
m[[2, All, 2]] ∈ H
```

> True

Comment: thank you for your answer, but doing as you said I then encountered some problems trying to do operations with function max. I edited my question because it took too long to explain the problems in comments, I hope it's all right.